# Смещение картинки в Firefox

Tags: firefox, вёрстка, css, браузер

Здравствуйте, коллеги.

Подскажите пожалуйста как решить один вопрос ярко выраженный в Firefox.

Недавно реализовывая проект на raphaeljs, столкнулся с тем что при переносе элемента мышкой, можно задеть фон и получается вот такой эффект:

[image]

Такое может произойти как и с обычной картинкой так и с картинкой вставленной через рафаэль. Этот эффект ярко наблюдается в файрфоксе, в остальных тоже есть но меньше.

Подскажите, возможно ли как-то запретить этот перенос для браузера.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('img').on('dragstart', function(event) { event.preventDefault(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю более элегантное решение на CSS:

```
img {
   pointer-events: none;
}
```